# Lua - writing for NGINX, debugging on console

Tags: nginx, lua

I am just learning some Lua for use in NGINX. I would like to know if something like this is possible, instead of keep restarting NGINX.

```
if package.loaded[ngx] then
 ngx.say
else
 print
end
```

is this possible?

Comment: no, i was wondering if someone has done something similar.

idealy something like this:

`function myecho(s)

Comment: `function myecho(s)
if package.loaded["ngx"] then
 ngx.say(s)
else
 print(s)
end
`

Comment: What exactly are you after? Is it just ngx.say you want to conditionally overwrite?